# Wait for a function to finish with promises

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I am trying to create a script with the logic:
do step 1
wait for step 1 to finish then do step 2

for step 1, I took this excellent code from here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/13051
which repeats a function at intervals:

```
var someFunc = function () {window.scrollBy(0, 500);}

function repeatXI(callback, interval, repeats, immediate) {
  var timer, trigger;
trigger = function () {
    callback();
    --repeats || clearInterval(timer);
  };

  interval = interval <= 0 ? 1000 : interval; // default: 1000ms
  repeats  = parseInt(repeats, 10) || 0;      // default: repeat forever
  timer    = setInterval(trigger, interval);

  if( !!immediate ) { // Coerce boolean
    trigger();
  }
}

repeatXI(someFunc, 1000, 5)
```

step 2 has this code:

```
if($('#smc').css('display') === 'block')
            {
                alert('iparxi')
                $('#smc').trigger('click');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('den iparxi')
                GM_setClipboard('1');
            }
```

The problem is that step 2 happens before step 1. From what I have read, in order to resolve this I must use Promises. Unfortunately I have read a dozen articles, and though I understand their logic I cant implement their syntax properly in my case. for example I try this:

```
let repeatXI = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

repeatXI(someFunc, 1000, 3).then(function(value) {
step 2 code
});
```

but nothing happens, it doesnt work at all. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `repeatXI` is a promise, not a function. What is the goal you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: i want to scroll down a page several times and then look for a specific web element. the problem is that it looks for the element before it first scrolls down.

Comment: Javascript automatically converts anything inside an ```if```, ```for``` or ```while``` condition to boolean. There is no need to use ```!!```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be solved through using promises, but for that the scrolling down needs to be promisified. But thats easy:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function() { // enter asynchronous code
   let count = 3;
   while(count--) {
     await delay(1000);
     window.scrollBy(0, 500);
   }
   if($('#smc').css('display') === 'block') {
      alert('iparxi')
      $('#smc').trigger('click');
   } else {
      alert('den iparxi')
      GM_setClipboard('1');
   }
})();
```

Comment: @jillim glad to help, if it answered your question you could mark it as answer :)